# Как можно реализовать функцию опроса в приложении?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Делаю приложение пытаюсь все сделать классно, но встрял с разработкой алгоритма(скорее всего из-за неопотности). В чем суть, есть класс в нем функция которая должна выводить из переданного массива вопросы и ответы из другого, потом ставит обработчики нажатий (у меня есть заготовка), потом ждет нажатия кнопки и переходит на следующий вопрос.

Имена кнопок и т.д (все передано в класс)

QuestionField - поле для вопроса

AnswerField1 - вариант ответа1

AnswerField1 - вариант ответа2

AnswerField1 - вариант ответа3

questions - массив вопросов

answers - массив ответов

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Массивы и прочие элементы:

```
String[] questions = {"вопрос1", "вопрос2", "вопрос3"};

//массив правильных ответов
String[] true_answers = {"ответ1", "ответ2", "ответ3"};

//массив ответов пользователя (значения меняются при ответах)
String[] user_answers = {" ", " ", " "};

//варианты ответа
Button AnswerField1, AnswerField2, AnswerField3;

TextView QuestionField;
```

Реализовать переход по вопросам можно вот так:

```
//получаем длину массивов
int Answers_length = answers.length;
int Questions_length = questions.length;

//переменная хранит текущий вопрос и обновляется после нажатия на кнопку ответа
int this_question = -1

//действия при нажатии на кнопку ответа
this_question++;
QuestionField.setText(questions[this_question]);
//если нажата правильная кнопка - в ячейку будет записан правильный ответ
user_answers[this_question] = "Вариант ответа";
```

Проверка ответов:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Answers_length; i++) {
     if(user_answers[i].equals(true_answers[i])){
          //какой-либо метод записи верно/неверно, можно снова с массив
     }
}
```

*Надеюсь, смог хоть чем-то помочь, или хотя бы подкинул идею :)*